# Unable to fetch all where userRole = "ManagerRole" from users table

Tags: java, jpql, named-query

This is my entity class.

```
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = UsersEntity.NAMED_QUERY_SELECT_ALL_BY_MANAGER_ROLE, 
                    query = "SELECT e FROM " + UsersEntity.ENTITY_NAME + " e WHERE e." + 
                                    UsersEntity.FIELD_NAME_USER_ROLE + " = '" +
                                    UsersVO.USER_ROLE + "'") })

@Column(name = "USER_ROLE", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String userRole;
    public static final String FIELD_NAME_USER_ROLE = "userRole";
```

This is the java class from where i execute query

```
@GET
@Path("/userrole")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public UsersListVO getUsers(@QueryParam("userRole") String userRole) {
 // public UsersListVO getUsers(){
    System.out.println(">>>>>here");
    UsersListVO usersListVO = new UsersListVO();
    try {
        List<UsersEntity> usersEntityList = em.createNamedQuery(UsersEntity.NAMED_QUERY_SELECT_ALL_BY_MANAGER_ROLE, UsersEntity.class).setParameter(UsersEntity.FIELD_NAME_USER_ROLE, userRole).getResultList();
```

The test case is :-

```
@Test
public void testGetUsers() {
    System.out.println("Start test ");
    UsersListVO usersListVO = baseWebTarget.path("userrole").queryParam("userRole", "AppSystemManagerUserRole").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(UsersListVO.class);
    if (usersListVO.getStatusType().equals(StatusTypeVO.FAILURE)) {
        Assert.fail(usersListVO.getMessage());
    } else {
        System.out.println(usersListVO.getMessage());        
    }
}
```

I want to fetch all the managers whose roles are managerRole from users table.But got error while executing the test case in to my jdeveloper. The error i got is

> java.lang.AssertionError: You have attempted to set a parameter value
>   using a name of userRole that does not exist in the query string
>   SELECT e FROM UsersEntity e WHERE e.userRole =
>   'AppSystemManagerUserRole'.

Comment: Please boil down your code to the minimum which reproduces your problem. Then it's more likely that someone tries to understand it.

Comment: @Heri sorry for that, can you check it now.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? All you ever need is the roles of a user, or whether a specific user is in a specific role. What do you need a list of managers for?

Comment: there is column in my adf that only managers approved the request, so i want to populate all the managers name in that filed through named query

Answer (score 0):

The error

`java.lang.AssertionError: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of userRole that does not exist in the query string SELECT e FROM UsersEntity e WHERE e.userRole = 'AppSystemManagerUserRole'` is indicating the you are trying to set a parameter that doesn't exist in your named query.

Your named query:

```
query = "SELECT e FROM " + UsersEntity.ENTITY_NAME + " e WHERE e." + 
 UsersEntity.FIELD_NAME_USER_ROLE + " = '" + UsersVO.USER_ROLE + "'"
```

after string concatenation results in:

```
query = "SELECT e FROM UsersEntity e WHERE e.userRole = 'AppSystemManagerUserRole'"
```

As you can see there is not named parameter that you can set. And when you tried calling `setParameter(UsersEntity.FIELD_NAME_USER_ROLE, userRole)` it threw the exception.

You need to introduce named parameter as below in your named query that you allows you to set later in your code.

```
query = "SELECT e FROM " + UsersEntity.ENTITY_NAME + " e WHERE e." + 
 UsersEntity.FIELD_NAME_USER_ROLE + " = :" + UsersEntity.FIELD_NAME_USER_ROLE
```

would result in the

```
query = "SELECT e FROM UsersEntity e WHERE e.userRole = :userRole"
```

With this you should be able to set the parameter and should work.